# Enable the Android market on a kobo vox

Tags: google-play-store

Based on its cheap price, I'm considering purchasing a [Kobo Vox](http://www.kobobooks.com/kobovox). The only downside I see to it is that it the market isn't enabled on it. Is there a way to enable the Android market on it once I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, only if your rooted. You would manually have to install the g-apps recovery update zip.

If you tell me your country and phone type, i can provide a link, or you can see all available versions here:

[GApps Downloads](http://goo-inside.me/gapps/)

Answer (score 1):

The kobo box is a cheap (price) tablet and it does have some issues. You better google and read about them before buying one.

That being said it can be made to run the Google Android Market. Note that you'll need `adb` or root'ing your device to do so. You'll also need to repeat those steps every time an update is available for the tablet (since it will rewrite the partition were you're making the changes).

Still interested ? ;-) If so then the best instructions for rooting and [installing](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=160948) the market are available on mobileread.com.

Have fun!